# How to store data into an array?

Tags: python, database

I have a slight problem as I'm not sure how to store data into an array and make it 'stay there'. The only way that works for temporary data is this:

```
c = {}
a = input('enter a letter')
d = {}
ab = input('enter a symbol to pair it with')
c = str(c)
d = str(d)
trans = str.maketrans(c,d) 
text = input('Enter Coded word')
print (text.translate(trans))
```

I was thinking that maybe a SQL table would be a way but I'm not too sure?

Comment: A lot of info missing here.  Lets start with what development framework you are using?

Comment: This is way, way too broad for Stack Overflow. Anything from "use a database" to "write it down on paper" would seem to be a valid answer. You're going to have to introduce some constraints on the scope of your question for it to be usefully answered.

Comment: I vote "write it down"

Comment: This is my first quation ive asked on here so you'll have to excuse how broad I am, its a general question that I thought alot of people may need answering.

Comment: +1, for cutting him some slack on his first question!

Comment: This isn't a web app or anything right?  Just a console application?  What exactly from above do you want to store and what does that data look like?

Comment: yup, its a challenge I got given by a friend, its too decode a list of words using the str.maketrans function.

Comment: When you say array do you mean a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)?

Comment: Basically im given a list of ten coded words and I make a program that allows the user to enter their own letter and symbol combinations, thats where im struggling with how to store the data that they enter for the next time they run the program

Comment: Okay well first check out this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_maketrans.htm). I think for the codes needed for the last part you can just use strings based on the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this chapter of the python documentation: [Data Persistence](http://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html), [Example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example)

In your case a file might be enough to store your data in.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_maketrans.htm) I would use from your code `a` and `ab` as the arguments for the `maketrans` call.

```
import string
from string import maketrans
a = input("What? ")
b = input("Yea? ")
trans = string.maketrans(a[:5], b[:5])
```